# На холме Яникул или Яникуле?

Tags: пунктуация, топонимика, склонение-имён-собственных

> В Риме каждый день в полдень стреляет пушка на самом высоком холме
>   Яникул – он по другую сторону Тибра. Посвящён он богу Начала и Конца –
>   Янусу, потому так и назван.

Знаки надо менять? Тире перед Яникул(ом), запятую за?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*В Риме каждый день в полдень стреляет пушка на самом высоком **холме Яникул** – он по другую сторону Тибра. Посвящён он богу Начала и Конца Янусу, потому так и назван.*

Или: Посвящён он Янусу — богу Начала и Конца, потому так и назван.

О согласовании  [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#з_07](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_07)

8. Названия озер, заливов, проливов, каналов, бухт, островов, полуостровов, гор, горных хребтов, пустынь и т.п., **как правило, не согласуются** с родовыми наименованиями, например: на горе Эльбрус; 
   Возможные варианты согласования относятся **к немногим хорошо знакомым названиям,** которые часто употребляются самостоятельно, без родового наименования, например: мимо острова Цусимы; северная половина острова Сахалина; на острове Сицилии; в пустыне Сахаре.